# How can I reorder list of item with Order column and update list with EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

I have list of object like this in database:

```
    List<YourEntity> entities = new List<YourEntity>
{
    new YourEntity { Id = 1, Name = "Item A", OrderColumn = 1 },
    new YourEntity { Id = 2, Name = "Item B", OrderColumn = 2 },
    new YourEntity { Id = 3, Name = "Item C", OrderColumn = 3 },
    // Add more items as needed
};
```

I want my user can change the `OrderColumn` value for Ordering the list and save new order in database.

what is the best way to do this with entity framework core?

also, I write some method to do this, but it has issue and can't correctly calculated order for other row when I change one of row.

My method is:

```
public static List<T> UpdateOrder(List<T> entities, Func<T, int> getOrder, Action<T, int> setOrder, int itemId, int newOrder)
{
    var itemToMove = entities.SingleOrDefault(e => getOrder(e) == itemId);

    if (itemToMove != null)
    {
        // Determine the current order of the item
        int currentOrder = getOrder(itemToMove);

        // Update the order of the item
        setOrder(itemToMove, newOrder);

        // Update the order of other items accordingly
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            int entityOrder = getOrder(entity);

            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(entity, itemToMove))
            {
                if (newOrder < currentOrder && entityOrder >= newOrder && entityOrder < currentOrder)
                {
                    setOrder(entity, entityOrder++);
                }
                else if (newOrder > currentOrder && entityOrder <= newOrder && entityOrder > currentOrder)
                {
                    setOrder(entity, entityOrder--);
                }
            }
        }

        // Reorder all items based on the new Order values and return the updated list
        entities = entities.OrderBy(getOrder).ToList();
    }

    return entities;
}
```

I am using this method like:

```
entities = OrderItemsHelper<YourEntity>.UpdateOrder(entities, e => e.Id, (e, order) => e.OrderColumn = order, item.Id, newOrder);
```

My Question: How can I be rearranging order of rows and updating other record?

Answer (score 1):

You have a mistake, you are mixing `Id` and `OrderColumn`, the `UpdateOrder` should be called as:

```cs
var o_entities = UpdateOrder(entities,
    getId: e => e.Id,  // <-- new!!!
    getOrder: e => e.OrderColumn,
    setOrder: (e, order) => e.OrderColumn = order,
    itemId: item.Id,
    newOrder: newOrder);
```

and change to:

```cs
private static List<T> UpdateOrder<T>(List<T> entities,
    Func<T, int> getId,  // <-- new!!!
    Func<T, int> getOrder,
    Action<T, int> setOrder,
    int itemId,
    int newOrder)
{
    var itemToMove = 
        entities
        .SingleOrDefault(e => getId(e) == itemId); // <-- getId !!!!
```

They are other major issues on your code like styling, algorithm, etc. <del>But, in my opinion, this question should have been posted on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site</del>.

Comment: You don't have 10k on Code Review so the link will be dead. However [the user posted the question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/287136) and I closed hammered the post. You should read our help center before recommending Code Review again.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I will do, thanks about advice.